# How to add and artifact located at openhab repository with Maven?

Tags: maven

I am looking to add a dependency to my pom.xml file

The dependency is a library allowing to manipulate Bluetooth Low Energy devices. Here is the link : [TinyB](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/intel-iot-devkit/tinyb/0.5.1)

Here is also the github of the library : [intel-iot-devkit/tinyb](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/tinyb)

When I copy and paste the snippet code to add the dependency, I get the following error after Maven tries to resolve the dependencies :

`Could not find artifact intel-iot-devkit:tinyb:pom:0.5.1 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)`

Could this be because the artifact is located in the OpenHab repository ? Then if this may cause the problem, how to solve it ?

Here is a copy of my pom.xml file :

```
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.HAcare</groupId>
    <artifactId>HAcare_Connector</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/intel-iot-devkit/tinyb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>intel-iot-devkit</groupId>
            <artifactId>tinyb</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>org.HAcare.App</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And here is the code snippet I added to pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>intel-iot-devkit</groupId>
    <artifactId>tinyb</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The problem is that the artifacts have been hosted on bintray which has gone down... so the maintainer must do something or you have to build it on your own...

Comment: Then I will try to contact the maintainer to see if it's possible to fix it. Thank you @khmarbaise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a second repository where it is possible to use this library by adding a dependency to the pom.xml file. Indeed it seems that the libraries are stored on the repository of openHAB.

To proceed you must first :

1. Add a repositories section in the pom.xml file

Here is a snippet code:

```
 <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>openHAB</id>
            <name>openHabTinyB</name>
            <url>https://openhab.jfrog.io/openhab/libs-release/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

2. You have to add the following dependency:

Here is a snippet code:

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openhab.osgiify/intel-iot-devkit.tinyb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openhab.osgiify</groupId>
            <artifactId>intel-iot-devkit.tinyb</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Ridha, thank you for this!